# Accessing variable from controller in html

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make an edit form pop-up as the show page but I am unable to get the data in popup html.
Pop-up Code:

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">I am a modal!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h1>{{ visitor11.first_name }}</h1>       
    <div ng-app="VisitorCenter" ng-controller="visitorsController">
      <div ng-repeat="visitor22 in visitors">
        <p>{{ visitor22.first_name }} {{ visitor22.last_name }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

But this "{{ visitor11.first_name }}" is not working.

Js file:

```
$scope.open = function (index) {

visitor = $scope.visitors[index]
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  // size: size,
  resolve: {
    visitor11: function(){
      alert(visitor.first_name +" "+ visitor.last_name);
      return visitor;
    }
  }
});

return visitor;

};
```

ModalInstanceCtrl:

```
 visitorCenter.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

   $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close();
   };

   $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
   };
 });
```

How can I get this 'visitor' object in my popup html.
Please don't try to make any sense of my code above because it won't make any. i am just doing random stuff for learning angularJs. Just look at the problem.

Comment: I don't see ModalInstanceCtrl defined in your HTML structure!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by modifying instance controller. I thought that 'return visitor' in resolve is passing this variable to my html but it was passing this to ModalInstanceCtrl controller.
Just added one line to use this in my html

```
visitorCenter.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, visitor11)        
{
    $scope.visitor11 = visitor11;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now this variable 'visitor11' is ready to be used in html.

Comment: If you looked at my answer, you would not have spent 15 days figuring out what was wrong :D

Answer (score 1):

You should do following in `ModalInstanceCtrl`:

```
function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, visitor11){
    $scope.visitor11 = visitor11;
}
```

To use variable in view, first it must be property of `$scope` object